# Golang Decode a BSON with special character Keys to a struct

Tags: go, bson

I have a Golang struct called `Person` where all the properties have to be exported:

```
type Person struct {
    Id         string
    Name       string 
}
```

Now I need to encode my MongoDB BSON response to this `Person` struct.  The BSON looks like:

```
{
  "_id": "ajshJSH78N",
  "Name": "Athavan Kanapuli"
}
```

The Golang code to encode the BSON is:

```
    mongoRecord := Person{}
    c := response.session.DB("mydb").C("users")
    err := c.Find(bson.M{"username": Credentials.Username, "password": Credentials.Password}).One(&mongoRecord)
```

**The Problem:**

1. `_id` is not getting encoded into `Id`
2. If I change the `Person` property into `_Id`, then it won't be exported.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: According to your answer, this question is wrong: You're not decoding JSON at all, rather BSON.

Answer (score 1):

Define your struct with `json` tag-

```
type Person struct {
    Id         string   `json:"_id"`
    Name       string  // this field match with json, so mapping not need
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put a json tag like ,

```
type Person struct {
    Id         string   `json:"_id"`
    Name       string  // this field match with json, so mapping not need
}
```

But still it didn't work.  Because the Mongodb returns '_id' which is of type bson.ObjectId  .  Hence changing the Struct tag to   `bson:"_id"` and the type of the Person struct has been changed from string to bson.ObjectId. The changes done are as follows ,

```
type Person struct {
    Id         bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Name       string
    UserName   string
    IsAdmin    bool
    IsApprover bool
}
```

And It works!

Comment: If the `bson` tag works, it's because you're not decoding JSON at all.